# React todolist showing empty

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks, axios, fullcalendar

When the user clicks the component I make a get request to my fetch_description which returns this exact response :

```
[{"Descrizione":"test1"},{"Descrizione":"test2"}]
```

What I want is to take what's in the response and put that into my modal. In my console.log(result.data) the data is shown correctly, so I think my issue is in operationList.js, in the map function but I don't understand what is wrong there.

However the modal I get is showing empty lists

```
 <li>
```

**My code is here:**

Calendar.js

```
const Calendar = () => {

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [operations, listOperations] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[listDayPlugin]}
      timeZone="local"
      locale="it"
      initialView="listDay"
      events="http://localhost:5000/parse_appointments"
      eventClick =
      {
        function(arg){
          Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/fetch_description", {
            params: {
              id: arg.event.id
            }
          })
          .then(
            (result) => {
              listOperations(result.data);
              setShow(true);
              console.log(result.data);
            }
          )
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
      }        
    />

    <Modal show={show} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
        <Modal.Header>Hi</Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>    
            <div>
            { operations ? 
              
              (
                <TodoList operations={operations}/>
              ) 
              
              : 
              
              (
                  <h1> Loading</h1>
              )
            }
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>This is the footer</Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
  </>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

operationList.js

```
const TodoList = ({ operations }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {operations.map((operation) => (
        <li
          key={operation.Descrizione}
        >
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty embarrassing but I got the error:

In my operationList.js I had

```
    <li key={operation.Descrizione}>
    </li>
```

Which basically created emptpy lists, so I changed to:

```
    <li key={operation.Descrizione}>
      {operation.Descrizione}
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "operations" variable is initialized as null, which does not include the "map" function.

you can simply initialize it as an empty array in your useState function call like this :

```
  const [operations, listOperations] = useState([]);
```

also you are not displaying anything inside your "li" tag, the "key" property does not render any text, you have to put it inside your tag, like this :

```
const TodoList = ({ operations }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {operations.map((operation) => (
        <li
          key={operation.Descrizione}
        >
            {operation.Descrizione}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

your callback after Api Call is also looking a bit wrong, all your code should be in the callback function, like this :

```
.then(
  (result) => {
    listOperations(result.data);
    setShow(true);
  }
)
```

Comment: This fixed partially...now i have an empty list, I mean I see the <li> but not the description...Any idea? I am sorry, really new to react

Comment: I had already changed it, still showing empty list :/

Comment: Have you modified the callback function as well ? if you did, try to log the value of "result.data" in console, to see what you exactly have in your object

Comment: What I am getting is :                                                                                                                                    Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { Descrizione: "test1" }
​
1: Object { Descrizione: "test2" }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
calendar.js:34

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit wrong:

```
.then(
   (result) => {listOperations(result.data)},
   setShow(true)
)
```

What it should be is:

```
.then(
  (result) => {
    listOperations(result.data);
    setShow(true);
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't solve my issue, but it helped...I updated my post